# Matrix decomposition definition

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

Wikipedia says "In the mathematical discipline of linear algebra, a matrix decomposition or matrix factorization is a factorization of a matrix into a **product of matrices**. There are many different matrix decompositions; each finds use among a particular class of problems."

But in my opinion decomposition term should be used to represent breaking a matrix in different sub-matrices or some new matrices created after some operation on original matrix which if used together and passed through some algorithm(not necessarily product), shall reproduce the original matrix.

Is there some different terminology to represent what I am expecting to say?

Comment: The term "decomposition" may sometimes be used in other ways as well; for example people sometimes speak of decomposing a matrix as a sum of simpler matrices.

Comment: @littleO: yes but it will create lot of zeros(wasting space), so I am not seeing if I can break it this way that I get rid of zeros. I want to break it in pieces such that it generates data, operable separately and used to regenerate again.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not sure if this is relevant, but people often use [block notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) with matrices.

Comment: @littleO : thanks, I am aware of these.

Comment: This "breaking" is usually referred to as "partitioning".

Answer (score 3):

"But in my opinion decomposition term should be used to represent breaking a matrix in different sub-matrices or some new matrices created after some operation on original matrix which if used together and passed through some algorithm(not necessarily product), shall reproduce the original matrix."

To give one of many examples, the $LU$ decomposition will

- **represent breaking a matrix** into two new matrices, namely $L$ and $U$.  These matrices are
- **created after some operation on** (the) **original matrix**, the operation being Gaussian elimination.  Then
- **if used together**, that is, the matrices $L$ and $U$ are used together, and
- **passed through some operation**, the operation being matrix multiplication, they
- **reproduce the original matrix**, because $LU=A$.

I think this fits perfectly into what you have said.  As far as I know there is no other commonly used term for this kind of thing.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is very costly operation in computer programs and LU creates almost double data on decomposition. I am saying why it is so dependent on product ? There could be other operations to regenerate right ?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to decompose and not depend on multiplication explicitly.

Comment: @Dave : I have contributed my answer too, please provide some input if you get time.

Comment: @Rorschach No, LU can be done in place without space overhead, and you are not decomposing just to multiply again. You are doing it to simplify other operations - solving equations, as a step in diagonalization or  something like that. Also, matrix multiplication is usually the least costly step (it's actually a unit of "time" for matrix algorithms). Every other algorithm (on full matrices), including the decompositions, are at best comparable, or much worse. O(n^3) of multiplication can be slightly reduced by Strassen/Winograd-style algorithms, which also improves other related algorithms.

Comment: @orion : i agree with you but I need to make repetitive operations on matrix and hence need to keep it all in RAM. I needed some way to break it in parts, perform operation on each and reconstruct it again. It is helping me in keeping minimum RAM busy at each run. Complexity of multiplication is $O(n^3)$ and rest(best being 2.3) are theoretical results only applicable to extremely large matrices, if I am not wrong.May be its not a fully optimized approach but it was something for me to learn certainly. I never read anything like this before. Never thought if echleon should be reversed.

Comment: @Rorschach partitioning into blocks is probably a better idea. Is your matrix really full? The algorithms and storage can be completely different if the matrices are sparse, block, band, or similar types. Decades established libraries should handle everything smoothly.

Yes, naive multiplication is O(n^3), but you can do better with divide-and-conquer approach (which is smartly used by libraries for large enough matrices where it helps with speed):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm

Comment: @orion: Recently there has been a [dramatic development in equations solving](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2958).
I think this approach can benefit a lot from this by getting rid of multiplications all together. This is the reason, I tried approaching it from a different side. Your suggestion on block matrices is also helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried answering this question, It was long so I am putting it as [link](http://www.academia.edu/7025276/Inverse_of_Row_reduction_by_solving_equations). I am not a mathematician but programmer, please provide some inputs.