# how to decompose matrix like this?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I want to have two matrixes of $ A $ and $B$ of a certain size, multiply them together $C = AB$, do some operations on $C$ to make $C_2$ and then decompose the matrix into to matrices of the same size as $A$ and $B$ so that $A_2B_2 = C_2$.

Which decomposition function can I use to achieve this?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate because the thread linked in the comments using LU decomposition says nothing about L and U being the same dimensions as the original matrix

Comment: See this website: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783222/matrix-decomposition-definition

Comment: @BadAtGeometry No, it's not the same question at all. The other question is about terminology, and makes no mention about the property being asked about in the current question.